# Open other Android Apps programmatically without resetting them

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

Opening an app like this on android always resets it to the main "home" state, dismissing any context that the user has been in previously:

```
val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appPackageName)
this.startActivity(intent)
```

Is there any way to launch another android app from within my app without that happening?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem when app is in the background. when app's process is destroyed, it's context is also lost. so you can't use it again. You can use the code below; if the second app is in the background, you can switch to it without reopening.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
val cn = ComponentName(
                    "Second app package name",
                    "com.example.example.YourActivityName"
                )
intent.component = cn
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
try {
    startActivity(intent)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Activity Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         .show()
}
```